# System.MissingMethodException in NInject

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, ninject

When running our unit tests on our TFS build server, we get this error:

```
SetUp : System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void
Ninject.ModuleLoadExtensions.Load(Ninject.IKernel, System.Reflection.Assembly[])'.
at Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.AssemblyScanner.Process(
Assembly assembly, IKernel kernel)
```

which, as far as I can tell, is saying that one part of NInject can't find another part of Ninject.

The problem occurs on all three of our build servers.

Locally, it works fine.

All systems (local & remote) appear to be using the correct version of all the Ninject assemblies (as well as all the other in the application)

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Ooops thought I mentioned this in the original message:

```
Ninject ver 2.2.0.0
Ninject.Extensions.Conventions  ver 2.2.0.5
```

Comment: Which version of Ninject and Ninject.Extensions.Conventions do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we figured it out.

TFS build server likes putting all DLLs in the same folder.  This causes a problem if you have both .Net and Silverlight assemblies with the same name (such is the case with Ninject.dll)

The solution was to change the "Output Path" on the Silverlight projects' properties page (under the "Build" tab), from the standard "`bin\Release\`" to something like "`bin\Release\Silverlight`" so the DLLs are kept separate.

Answer (score 4):

Moste likely you use different versions of Ninject.dll and Nnject.Extensions.Conventions. E.g Ninject 3.0.0 and Conventions 2.2.0

MissingMethod exception is a deployment problem. Use the Fusion log to check what is really loaded. E.g one assembly could be in the GAC.

Comment: If I'm reading the Fusion log right (BTW, thanks for the tip.  never knew about the Fusion log before), it IS loading the DLL from the projects BIN folder, and they are they current 2.2.0.0 vers.